# How to install Oracle Goldengate 21 Microservices for Oracle and MySQL

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

So I am kind of confused here.  I want to migrate a DB from MySQL to Oracle and want to use GG to do it.  I have a running version of GG 21.11 Microservices for Oracle.  I am trying to figure out if I install GG 21.3 Microservices for MySQL does it actually need a complete new webportal with its own Service Manager or can I choose that one that belongs to the Oracle install?  Then once I run the install I use the oggca.sh to create a deployment from the GG for MySQL install directory.  Will that deployment have everything I need to connect to a source, MySQL, and a target Oracle?  Thanks in advance.  and extra piece of info this is a Hub Goldengate setup.